# get_or_create using django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

is there a way to use get_or_create in views?

this is my models.py

```
class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=512, unique=True)
    short_url = models.URLField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
```

and my views.py is like this.

```
if oplinkform:
    oplink = Link.objects.get_or_create(url = oplinkform.data['url'])
    oplink.save()
```

i should get a link object with it .. right?
it is serving me a tuple... why?

This is the error i got with django.

```
AttributeError at /home/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'
Request Method: POST
```

//mouse

Answer (score 3):

[`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns a tuple of `(object, created)` where `created` is a boolean indicating if it was created.

Try this:

```
oplink, created = Link.objects.get_or_create(url = oplinkform.data['url'])
```